# Double-checking understanding of memory coalescing in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

Suppose I define some arrays which are visible to the GPU:

```
double* doubleArr = createCUDADouble(fieldLen);
float* floatArr = createCUDAFloat(fieldLen);
char* charArr = createCUDAChar(fieldLen);
```

Now, I have the following CUDA thread:

```
void thread(){
  int o = getOffset(); // the same for all threads in launch
  double d = doubleArr[threadIdx.x + o];
  float f = floatArr[threadIdx.x + o];
  char c = charArr[threadIdx.x + o];
}
```

I'm not quite sure whether I correctly interpret the documentation, and its very critical for my design: **Will the memory accesses for double, float and char be nicely coalesced?** (Guess: Yes, it will fit into `sizeof(type) * blockSize.x / (transaction size)` transactions, plus maybe one extra transaction at the upper and lower boundary.)

Comment: I do not understand why this question gets downvotes. What rules does it violate or what do I need to improve?

Comment: There's only about 10^99 questions on memory coalescing, many of which include links to documentation and presentations to help clarify their explanations. Looking at your question, first of all you cannot make an array "visible to the GPU" like this: `double* doubleArr = new double[fieldLen];` Next, does `getOffset` depend on any built-in variables such as `threadIdx.x` ?  Overall this question looks very much like it is plowing the same SoA vs. AoS ground. Your structure question cannot be answered unless you *show how you access the structure*.  are you loading a `char` or `char3` quantity?

Comment: BTW I didn't downvote your question.  I can easily prove that ;-)

Comment: Ok, THAT's helpful. So I tried to fix the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for all the cases you have shown, and assuming `createCUDAxxxxx` translates into some kind of ordinary `cudaMalloc` type operation, everything should nicely coalesce.

If we have ordinary 1D device arrays allocated via `cudaMalloc`, in general we should have good coalescing behavior across threads if our load pattern includes an array index of the form:

```
data_array[some_constant + threadIdx.x];
```

It really does not matter what data type the array is - it will coalesce nicely.

However, from a performance perspective, global loads (assuming an L1 miss) will occur in a minimum 128-byte granularity.  Therefore loading larger sizes per thread (say, `int`, `float`, `double`, `float4`, etc.) may give slightly better performance.  The caches tend to mitigate any difference, if the loads are across a large enough number of warps.

It's pretty easy also to verify this on a particular piece of code with a [profiler](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#abstract).  There are many ways to do this depending on which profiler you choose, but for example with nvprof you can do:

```
nvprof --metric gld_efficiency ./my_exe
```

and it will return an average percentage number that more or less exactly reflects the percentage of optimal coalescing that is occurring on global loads.

[This](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2012/presentations/S0514-GTC2012-GPU-Performance-Analysis.pdf) is the presentation I usually cite for additional background info on memory optimization.

I suppose someone will come along and notice that this pattern:

```
data_array[some_constant + threadIdx.x];
```

roughly corresponds to the access type shown on slides 40-41 of the above presentation. And *aha!!* efficiency drops to 50%-80%.  That is true, if only a single warp-load is being considered.  However, referring to slide 40, we see that the "first" load will require two cachelines to be loaded. *After that* however, additional loads (moving to the right, for simplicity) will only require one additional/new cacheline per warp-load (assuming the existence of an L1 or L2 cache, and reasonable locality, i.e. lack of thrashing). Therefore, over a reasonably large array (more than just 128 bytes), the *average* requirement will be one new cacheline per warp, which corresponds to 100% efficiency.